# Autocomplete returning 0 rather than usable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, auto

I have this Autocomplete which functions as an employee search field.  A user searches by the employee name and chooses a name from the list of results.  <s>My `onChange` logs the value and is return 0, rather than an employee name.  Can the employee name be sent rather than the index of the name in the results list?</s>

When an employee creates a document and labels themselves as document owner, their badge number is saved rather than their name.  This is because there are multiple employees all with the same name.

After clicking on a name from the autocomplete results, the name needs to be displayed in the autocomplete field, and the employee badge needs to be sent to `onBadgeChange` to be saved.

The function `onNameChange` is queried on each keystroke.

```
const { onChange, badge, taxonomyid, label, id, disabled, style, status, ...other } = props;
const [employees, setemployees] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEmployees = async () => {
        var url = `/api/employeesearch?taxonomyid=${taxonomyid}`;
        console.log(badge);
        if (badge && +badge) {
            url = url + `&badge=${badge}`;
            const resp = await fetch(url);
            const emp = await resp.json();
            setemployees(emp);
        }
    };
    fetchEmployees();
}, [badge, taxonomyid]);

const onNameChange = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = e.target.value;
    var url = `/api/employeesearch?taxonomyid=${taxonomyid}`;
    if (value) {
        url = url + `&name=${value}`;
        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const emp = await resp.json();
        if (resp.ok) {
            setemployees(emp);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        console.log(value);
    }
};

const onBadgeChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value);
    // console.log(e.target.name);
};
...
<Autocomplete
    id="search-select"
    // value={employees?.employees?.Name}
    //inputValue
    options={employees.employees}
    getOptionLabel={(option, i) => option.Name}
    onInputChange={(e) => onNameChange(e)}
    onChange={(e) => onBadgeChange(e)}
    filterOptions={(x) => x}
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    name={id || "Person"}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} variant="outlined" />}
/>
```

This is a quick example of employee data:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "Badge": "1234567",
      "Name": "Doe, John[John.Doe@gmail.com]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "Can the employee name be sent rather than the index of the name in the results list?" Sent where?

Comment: I am trying to send the employee name into the `onBadgeChange` funciton,

Comment: Have you tried `e.target.innerText`? Or `e.currentTarget.innerText`?

Comment: I did just a few minutes ago.  The issue has changed now though unfortunately.  I need to display the employee name, but send the Badge to `onBadgeChange`.  I will take a few minutes to reflect this in the question.

Comment: Question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#controlled-states):

Function passed to `onInputChange` have to arguments:

```
onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
  setInputValue(newInputValue);
}}
```

You want to use the second one